# Material-ui makeStyles with both before and after

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, jss, makestyles

I'm working on a project which requires the following CSS code.

```css
.hexagon, .hexagon::before, .hexagon::after {
  width: 67px;
  height: 116px;
  border-radius: 18%/5%;
}
```

Is there a way to implement the above style using Material-UI `makeStyles` without separate use of before and after selectors?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the below code, `'&'` means the generated class name that will be passed to the component

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    "&, &:before, &:after": {
      // your styles
    }
  }
});
```

```
<div className={classes.root}>
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]